# How to Export Chart and Legend to PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need help Export Chart and Legend to PDF

Sample code link [`JsFiddle Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/39me4mm8/6/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just added those libraries to your code and its working..

jsPDF-master/plugins/png_support.js

jsPDF-master/libs/png_support/png.js

jsPDF-master/libs/png_support/zlib.js

jsPDF-master/plugins/addimage.js

jsPDF-master/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSever.js

You need to download the file [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) too and paste it to the jsPDF-master/libs/FileSaver.js/